# Add custom next slide button to Unslider script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider

I use the unslider.js slider script.
By the way I can recommend it to everyone.

I'm trying to add an 'to next slide' button inside a slide.
First I added the same class to the button as the class from the next arrow link. But it doesn't work.

Is there a possibility to do this?

Thank you

```
**JS**
            var unslider = $('.banner').unslider({

        complete: function() {},
        keys: true,
        dots: false,
        fluid: false,
        nav: false
    });

    $('.unslider-arrow').click(function() {
        var fn = this.className.split(' ')[1];

        unslider.data('unslider')[fn]();
    });


**HTML snippet**

<a href="" class="unslider-arrow">To next slide</a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qATC9/45/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you need to set an href like this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="unslider-arrow">To next slide</a>
```

to prevent navigation. Then in jQuery

```
$('.unslider-arrow').click(function() {
    unslider.data('unslider').next();
});
```

see [updated FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qATC9/47/)

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help you

just use this code

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="banner-wrapper">
    <div class="banner">
        <ul>
            <li>  <a href="#" class="unslider-arrow next">To next slide</a><img src="https://picjumbo.imgix.net/HNCK0785.jpg?q=40&w=1650&sharp=30" /></li>
            <li> <a href="#" class="unslider-arrow next">To next slide</a><img src="https://picjumbo.imgix.net/HNCK0785.jpg?q=40&w=1650&sharp=30" /></li>
            <li> <a href="#" class="unslider-arrow next">To next slide</a><img src="https://picjumbo.imgix.net/HNCK0785.jpg?q=40&w=1650&sharp=30" /></li>

        </ul>
        <div class="banner-controls">
            <a href="#" class="unslider-arrow prev">&larr;</a>
            <a href="#" class="unslider-arrow next">&rarr;</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Check it here on FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qATC9/46/)